# Disable Safari Top Sites on Mavericks

Tags: safari

How can I disable the Top Sites on OS X ver 10.9.5? I have deleted the cache and locked Safari so that new windows images do not get saved.

I know how to Delete but need to know how to Disable the Top Sites in Safari.

Comment: As per your comment, I changed the Delete to Disable. If you think this is a error let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder paste following in the Go To Folder

```
 ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/
```

Right click on the  Webpage Previews Folder and select- Get Info

In Get info window select Locked.

From now on Safari will not save Top pages in that folder any more.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that but Top Sites still does its thing.

Comment: Did you restart Safari after locking the folder?